# FDIV how to use it in nasm, assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

i have a sum value stored in

```
fstp    qword [ebx]  ; Copy contents of st0 to space currently on top of the system stack
```

how do i divide it by an integer value that is stored in register edi?

i thought it was just

```
fdiv edi
```

but it says invalid combination of....blah blah blha

insight?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The FPU does not have access to the integer registers.

Comment: i was thinking maybe this would work       fstp    qword [ebx]       ;Copy contents of st0 to space currently on top of the system stack
 fld qword [edi] ;move edi onto FPU
 fdiv   ; divide?
 fstp qword [ebx] ;copy the result to print it out

Comment: why not just push edi, fdiv [esp]?

Answer (score 0):

As Jens says in his answer, the FPU does not have any direct access to the integer registers. You will need to use scratch memory to make the transfer. This is one of the major disadvantages of the x87 FPU. Example code might look something like:

```
section .bss
fpscratch: resd 1
```

...

```
section .text

;other code goes here

MOV fpscratch, edi
FILD fpscratch
FDIV
```

(Note on the above code: it has not been tested, obviously, and I'm a little rusty on my assembly so there is probably something wrong with it, even though it's nice and short.)

Comment: i tried that and it doesn't work, however i'm working this code right now and it's outputting -nan

Comment: fild qword   [ebp+12] 
 fstp    qword [ebx]   ;Copy contents of st0 to space currently on top of the system stack

 ;mov fpscratch, edi
 ;fild    edi
 fdiv 
 fstp    qword [ebx]   ;Copy contents of st0 to space currently on top of the system stack